# How isolate values defined by limiting functions and put them into another function to show as 3d plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

[My 2d plot with lines limiting my region of interst as black (colored in paint)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT1th.png)

I have this plot made with this code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
x = np.linspace(0.04,0.5,50)
y = np.linspace(0.04,0.5,50)
lime = 0.22-x
xmin = 0.05
xmax = 0.25
ymin = 0.04
ymax = 0.34
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axhline(ymax, label = "ymax", color = "r")
plt.axhline(ymin, label = "ymin", color = "b")
plt.axvline(xmax, label = "xmax", color = "g")
plt.axvline(xmin, label = "xmin", color = "y")
plt.plot(x, lime, label = "y = 0.22-x", color = "#451B94")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to take all the values that make up the black region, and then either highlight them on a 3d plot after i shove x and y into another function to define Z value or only plot the highlighted region. How do i do that?